# Java Garbage collection delays

Tags: java, garbage-collection

**Back ground:**
We are running a Spring Batch Java application on a 6 core linux host using Open JDK 11, we run multiple instances of app on the host.

GC Config is shown below
-XX:+UseG1GC -Xms3G -Xmx3G -Xlog:gc*=debug -Xloggc:/applogs/api_as_m01/gc01.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:ParallelGCThreads=16 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC

**Issue:**
GC pattern seems unpredictable, in most of the cases it waits for memory usage to reach >85% to initiate GC even though the memory is not being used and ready for GC, this is confirmed by external GC trigger when we take memory snapshot. It is not clear on why it waits for >85% memory usage, app never gets OOM even with out any intervention as GC happens ultimately. It runs GC twice or thrice in the entire day.

What could be causing this delay, how can we make sure GC runs normally to keep memory usage normal?

**GC Log:**

```
    [0.820s][info][gc,heap] Heap region size: 1M
[0.852s][info][gc     ] Using G1
[0.852s][info][gc,heap,coops] Heap address: 0x0000000700000000, size: 3072 MB, Compressed Oops mode: Zero based, Oop shift amount: 3
[2.149s][info][gc,start     ] GC(0) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause)
[2.150s][info][gc,task      ] GC(0) Using 6 workers of 6 for evacuation
[2.158s][info][gc,phases    ] GC(0)   Pre Evacuate Collection Set: 0.2ms
[2.158s][info][gc,phases    ] GC(0)   Evacuate Collection Set: 6.3ms
[2.158s][info][gc,phases    ] GC(0)   Post Evacuate Collection Set: 1.4ms
[2.159s][info][gc,phases    ] GC(0)   Other: 1.3ms
[2.159s][info][gc,heap      ] GC(0) Eden regions: 153->0(147)
[2.159s][info][gc,heap      ] GC(0) Survivor regions: 0->6(20)
[2.159s][info][gc,heap      ] GC(0) Old regions: 0->0
[2.159s][info][gc,heap      ] GC(0) Humongous regions: 2->0
[2.159s][info][gc,metaspace ] GC(0) Metaspace: 15725K->15725K(1064960K)
[2.159s][info][gc           ] GC(0) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 155M->5M(3072M) 9.642ms
[2.159s][info][gc,cpu       ] GC(0) User=0.03s Sys=0.00s Real=0.01s
[2.596s][info][gc,start     ] GC(1) Pause Young (Concurrent Start) (Metadata GC Threshold)
[2.596s][info][gc,task      ] GC(1) Using 6 workers of 6 for evacuation
[2.604s][info][gc,phases    ] GC(1)   Pre Evacuate Collection Set: 0.1ms
[2.604s][info][gc,phases    ] GC(1)   Evacuate Collection Set: 6.0ms
[2.604s][info][gc,phases    ] GC(1)   Post Evacuate Collection Set: 1.0ms
[2.605s][info][gc,phases    ] GC(1)   Other: 0.9ms
[2.605s][info][gc,heap      ] GC(1) Eden regions: 80->0(146)
[2.605s][info][gc,heap      ] GC(1) Survivor regions: 6->7(20)
[2.605s][info][gc,heap      ] GC(1) Old regions: 0->0
[2.605s][info][gc,heap      ] GC(1) Humongous regions: 0->0
[2.605s][info][gc,metaspace ] GC(1) Metaspace: 20745K->20745K(1069056K)
[2.605s][info][gc           ] GC(1) Pause Young (Concurrent Start) (Metadata GC Threshold) 85M->7M(3072M) 8.561ms
[2.605s][info][gc,cpu       ] GC(1) User=0.02s Sys=0.01s Real=0.01s
[2.605s][info][gc           ] GC(2) Concurrent Cycle
[2.605s][info][gc,marking   ] GC(2) Concurrent Clear Claimed Marks
[2.605s][info][gc,marking   ] GC(2) Concurrent Clear Claimed Marks 0.026ms
[2.605s][info][gc,marking   ] GC(2) Concurrent Scan Root Regions
[2.607s][info][gc,marking   ] GC(2) Concurrent Scan Root Regions 1.881ms
[2.607s][info][gc,marking   ] GC(2) Concurrent Mark (2.607s)
[2.607s][info][gc,marking   ] GC(2) Concurrent Mark From Roots
[2.607s][info][gc,task      ] GC(2) Using 2 workers of 2 for marking
[2.609s][info][gc,marking   ] GC(2) Concurrent Mark From Roots 2.184ms
[2.609s][info][gc,marking   ] GC(2) Concurrent Preclean
[2.609s][info][gc,marking   ] GC(2) Concurrent Preclean 0.197ms
[2.609s][info][gc,marking   ] GC(2) Concurrent Mark (2.607s, 2.609s) 2.417ms
[2.609s][info][gc,start     ] GC(2) Pause Remark
[2.612s][info][gc,stringtable] GC(2) Cleaned string and symbol table, strings: 9132 processed, 0 removed, symbols: 69213 processed, 643 removed
[2.612s][info][gc            ] GC(2) Pause Remark 8M->8M(3072M) 3.027ms
[2.612s][info][gc,cpu        ] GC(2) User=0.01s Sys=0.00s Real=0.00s
[2.612s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(2) Concurrent Rebuild Remembered Sets
[2.613s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(2) Concurrent Rebuild Remembered Sets 0.185ms
[2.613s][info][gc,start      ] GC(2) Pause Cleanup
[2.613s][info][gc            ] GC(2) Pause Cleanup 8M->8M(3072M) 0.511ms
[2.613s][info][gc,cpu        ] GC(2) User=0.00s Sys=0.00s Real=0.00s
[2.613s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(2) Concurrent Cleanup for Next Mark
[2.619s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(2) Concurrent Cleanup for Next Mark 6.174ms
[2.620s][info][gc            ] GC(2) Concurrent Cycle 14.778ms
[3.208s][info][gc,start      ] GC(3) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause)
[3.208s][info][gc,task       ] GC(3) Using 6 workers of 6 for evacuation
[3.217s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(3)   Pre Evacuate Collection Set: 0.3ms
[3.217s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(3)   Evacuate Collection Set: 6.3ms
[3.217s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(3)   Post Evacuate Collection Set: 1.4ms
[3.218s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(3)   Other: 0.8ms
[3.218s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(3) Eden regions: 146->0(157)
[3.218s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(3) Survivor regions: 7->9(20)
[3.218s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(3) Old regions: 0->0
[3.218s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(3) Humongous regions: 0->0
[3.218s][info][gc,metaspace  ] GC(3) Metaspace: 27168K->27168K(1073152K)
[3.218s][info][gc            ] GC(3) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 153M->8M(3072M) 9.920ms
[3.218s][info][gc,cpu        ] GC(3) User=0.03s Sys=0.00s Real=0.01s
[3.848s][info][gc,start      ] GC(4) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause)
[3.848s][info][gc,task       ] GC(4) Using 6 workers of 6 for evacuation
[3.858s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(4)   Pre Evacuate Collection Set: 0.1ms
[3.858s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(4)   Evacuate Collection Set: 8.4ms
[3.859s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(4)   Post Evacuate Collection Set: 1.3ms
[3.859s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(4)   Other: 0.7ms
[3.859s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(4) Eden regions: 157->0(170)
[3.859s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(4) Survivor regions: 9->11(21)
[3.859s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(4) Old regions: 0->0
[3.859s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(4) Humongous regions: 0->0
[3.859s][info][gc,metaspace  ] GC(4) Metaspace: 31520K->31520K(1077248K)
[3.859s][info][gc            ] GC(4) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 165M->10M(3072M) 11.289ms
[3.859s][info][gc,cpu        ] GC(4) User=0.06s Sys=0.00s Real=0.01s
[4.299s][info][gc,start      ] GC(5) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause)
[4.299s][info][gc,task       ] GC(5) Using 6 workers of 6 for evacuation
[4.309s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(5)   Pre Evacuate Collection Set: 0.1ms
[4.309s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(5)   Evacuate Collection Set: 7.5ms
[4.309s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(5)   Post Evacuate Collection Set: 1.5ms
[4.309s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(5)   Other: 0.8ms
[4.310s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(5) Eden regions: 170->0(195)
[4.310s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(5) Survivor regions: 11->12(23)
[4.310s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(5) Old regions: 0->0
[4.310s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(5) Humongous regions: 0->0
[4.310s][info][gc,metaspace  ] GC(5) Metaspace: 32118K->32118K(1079296K)
[4.310s][info][gc            ] GC(5) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 180M->12M(3072M) 10.921ms
[4.310s][info][gc,cpu        ] GC(5) User=0.05s Sys=0.01s Real=0.01s
[5.014s][info][gc,start      ] GC(6) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause)
[5.014s][info][gc,task       ] GC(6) Using 6 workers of 6 for evacuation
[5.030s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(6)   Pre Evacuate Collection Set: 0.2ms
[5.031s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(6)   Evacuate Collection Set: 14.0ms
[5.031s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(6)   Post Evacuate Collection Set: 1.4ms
[5.031s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(6)   Other: 0.7ms
[5.031s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(6) Eden regions: 195->0(269)
[5.031s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(6) Survivor regions: 12->14(26)
[5.031s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(6) Old regions: 0->0
[5.031s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(6) Humongous regions: 0->0
[5.031s][info][gc,metaspace  ] GC(6) Metaspace: 33683K->33683K(1079296K)
[5.031s][info][gc            ] GC(6) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 207M->13M(3072M) 16.989ms
[5.031s][info][gc,cpu        ] GC(6) User=0.06s Sys=0.00s Real=0.01s
[5.415s][info][gc,start      ] GC(7) Pause Young (Concurrent Start) (Metadata GC Threshold)
[5.416s][info][gc,task       ] GC(7) Using 6 workers of 6 for evacuation
[5.436s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(7)   Pre Evacuate Collection Set: 0.3ms
[5.436s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(7)   Evacuate Collection Set: 18.2ms
[5.437s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(7)   Post Evacuate Collection Set: 1.6ms
[5.437s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(7)   Other: 1.0ms
[5.437s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(7) Eden regions: 43->0(274)
[5.438s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(7) Survivor regions: 14->13(36)
[5.438s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(7) Old regions: 0->0
[5.438s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(7) Humongous regions: 0->0
[5.438s][info][gc,metaspace  ] GC(7) Metaspace: 35053K->35053K(1081344K)
[5.438s][info][gc            ] GC(7) Pause Young (Concurrent Start) (Metadata GC Threshold) 56M->12M(3072M) 22.239ms
[5.438s][info][gc,cpu        ] GC(7) User=0.05s Sys=0.00s Real=0.02s
[5.438s][info][gc            ] GC(8) Concurrent Cycle
[5.438s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(8) Concurrent Clear Claimed Marks
[5.438s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(8) Concurrent Clear Claimed Marks 0.037ms
[5.438s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(8) Concurrent Scan Root Regions
[5.443s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(8) Concurrent Scan Root Regions 4.721ms
[5.443s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(8) Concurrent Mark (5.443s)
[5.443s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(8) Concurrent Mark From Roots
[5.443s][info][gc,task       ] GC(8) Using 2 workers of 2 for marking
[5.445s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(8) Concurrent Mark From Roots 2.352ms
[5.445s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(8) Concurrent Preclean
[5.445s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(8) Concurrent Preclean 0.183ms
[5.445s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(8) Concurrent Mark (5.443s, 5.445s) 2.563ms
[5.446s][info][gc,start      ] GC(8) Pause Remark
[5.450s][info][gc,stringtable] GC(8) Cleaned string and symbol table, strings: 15971 processed, 0 removed, symbols: 114522 processed, 1048 removed
[5.451s][info][gc            ] GC(8) Pause Remark 13M->13M(3072M) 5.120ms
[5.451s][info][gc,cpu        ] GC(8) User=0.02s Sys=0.00s Real=0.00s
[5.451s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(8) Concurrent Rebuild Remembered Sets
[5.451s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(8) Concurrent Rebuild Remembered Sets 0.210ms
[5.451s][info][gc,start      ] GC(8) Pause Cleanup
[5.452s][info][gc            ] GC(8) Pause Cleanup 13M->13M(3072M) 0.787ms
[5.452s][info][gc,cpu        ] GC(8) User=0.00s Sys=0.00s Real=0.00s
[5.452s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(8) Concurrent Cleanup for Next Mark
[5.459s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(8) Concurrent Cleanup for Next Mark 7.293ms
[5.460s][info][gc            ] GC(8) Concurrent Cycle 21.721ms
[7.673s][info][gc,start      ] GC(9) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause)
[7.673s][info][gc,task       ] GC(9) Using 6 workers of 6 for evacuation
[7.701s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(9)   Pre Evacuate Collection Set: 0.1ms
[7.701s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(9)   Evacuate Collection Set: 24.5ms
[7.701s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(9)   Post Evacuate Collection Set: 2.6ms
[7.702s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(9)   Other: 0.8ms
[7.702s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(9) Eden regions: 274->0(416)
[7.702s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(9) Survivor regions: 13->20(36)
[7.702s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(9) Old regions: 0->0
[7.702s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(9) Humongous regions: 0->0
[7.702s][info][gc,metaspace  ] GC(9) Metaspace: 50170K->50170K(1093632K)
[7.702s][info][gc            ] GC(9) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 286M->19M(3072M) 28.946ms
[7.702s][info][gc,cpu        ] GC(9) User=0.14s Sys=0.01s Real=0.03s
[9.122s][info][gc,start      ] GC(10) Pause Young (Concurrent Start) (Metadata GC Threshold)
[9.122s][info][gc,task       ] GC(10) Using 6 workers of 6 for evacuation
[9.149s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(10)   Pre Evacuate Collection Set: 0.2ms
[9.149s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(10)   Evacuate Collection Set: 23.6ms
[9.150s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(10)   Post Evacuate Collection Set: 2.4ms
[9.150s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(10)   Other: 0.9ms
[9.150s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(10) Eden regions: 383->0(1822)
[9.150s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(10) Survivor regions: 20->21(55)
[9.150s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(10) Old regions: 0->0
[9.150s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(10) Humongous regions: 116->0
[9.150s][info][gc,metaspace  ] GC(10) Metaspace: 58602K->58602K(1101824K)
[9.150s][info][gc            ] GC(10) Pause Young (Concurrent Start) (Metadata GC Threshold) 518M->21M(3072M) 27.755ms
[9.150s][info][gc,cpu        ] GC(10) User=0.06s Sys=0.01s Real=0.03s
[9.150s][info][gc            ] GC(11) Concurrent Cycle
[9.150s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(11) Concurrent Clear Claimed Marks
[9.150s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(11) Concurrent Clear Claimed Marks 0.063ms
[9.150s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(11) Concurrent Scan Root Regions
[9.158s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(11) Concurrent Scan Root Regions 7.274ms
[9.158s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(11) Concurrent Mark (9.158s)
[9.158s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(11) Concurrent Mark From Roots
[9.158s][info][gc,task       ] GC(11) Using 2 workers of 2 for marking
[9.160s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(11) Concurrent Mark From Roots 2.116ms
[9.160s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(11) Concurrent Preclean
[9.160s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(11) Concurrent Preclean 0.183ms
[9.160s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(11) Concurrent Mark (9.158s, 9.160s) 2.344ms
[9.160s][info][gc,start      ] GC(11) Pause Remark
[9.168s][info][gc,stringtable] GC(11) Cleaned string and symbol table, strings: 28616 processed, 0 removed, symbols: 186406 processed, 144 removed
[9.169s][info][gc            ] GC(11) Pause Remark 22M->22M(3072M) 8.840ms
[9.169s][info][gc,cpu        ] GC(11) User=0.03s Sys=0.00s Real=0.01s
[9.169s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(11) Concurrent Rebuild Remembered Sets
[9.169s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(11) Concurrent Rebuild Remembered Sets 0.165ms
[9.169s][info][gc,start      ] GC(11) Pause Cleanup
[9.170s][info][gc            ] GC(11) Pause Cleanup 22M->22M(3072M) 0.494ms
[9.170s][info][gc,cpu        ] GC(11) User=0.00s Sys=0.00s Real=0.00s
[9.170s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(11) Concurrent Cleanup for Next Mark
[9.173s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(11) Concurrent Cleanup for Next Mark 3.106ms
[9.173s][info][gc            ] GC(11) Concurrent Cycle 22.854ms
[18.224s][info][gc,start      ] GC(12) Pause Young (Concurrent Start) (Metadata GC Threshold)
[18.224s][info][gc,task       ] GC(12) Using 6 workers of 6 for evacuation
[18.270s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(12)   Pre Evacuate Collection Set: 0.3ms
[18.270s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(12)   Evacuate Collection Set: 39.4ms
[18.270s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(12)   Post Evacuate Collection Set: 4.6ms
[18.271s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(12)   Other: 1.4ms
[18.271s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(12) Eden regions: 1245->0(1278)
[18.271s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(12) Survivor regions: 21->39(231)
[18.271s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(12) Old regions: 0->0
[18.271s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(12) Humongous regions: 116->0
[18.271s][info][gc,metaspace  ] GC(12) Metaspace: 98134K->98134K(1136640K)
[18.271s][info][gc            ] GC(12) Pause Young (Concurrent Start) (Metadata GC Threshold) 1382M->38M(3072M) 46.731ms
[18.271s][info][gc,cpu        ] GC(12) User=0.13s Sys=0.01s Real=0.04s
[18.271s][info][gc            ] GC(13) Concurrent Cycle
[18.271s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(13) Concurrent Clear Claimed Marks
[18.271s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(13) Concurrent Clear Claimed Marks 0.148ms
[18.271s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(13) Concurrent Scan Root Regions
[18.283s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(13) Concurrent Scan Root Regions 11.947ms
[18.283s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(13) Concurrent Mark (18.283s)
[18.283s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(13) Concurrent Mark From Roots
[18.283s][info][gc,task       ] GC(13) Using 2 workers of 2 for marking
[18.285s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(13) Concurrent Mark From Roots 2.302ms
[18.285s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(13) Concurrent Preclean
[18.286s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(13) Concurrent Preclean 0.209ms
[18.286s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(13) Concurrent Mark (18.283s, 18.286s) 2.545ms
[18.286s][info][gc,start      ] GC(13) Pause Remark
[18.295s][info][gc,stringtable] GC(13) Cleaned string and symbol table, strings: 46621 processed, 0 removed, symbols: 284121 processed, 119 removed
[18.296s][info][gc            ] GC(13) Pause Remark 41M->41M(3072M) 10.091ms
[18.296s][info][gc,cpu        ] GC(13) User=0.04s Sys=0.00s Real=0.01s
[18.296s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(13) Concurrent Rebuild Remembered Sets
[18.296s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(13) Concurrent Rebuild Remembered Sets 0.224ms
[18.297s][info][gc,start      ] GC(13) Pause Cleanup
[18.297s][info][gc            ] GC(13) Pause Cleanup 41M->41M(3072M) 0.568ms
[18.297s][info][gc,cpu        ] GC(13) User=0.00s Sys=0.00s Real=0.00s
[18.297s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(13) Concurrent Cleanup for Next Mark
[18.300s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(13) Concurrent Cleanup for Next Mark 3.352ms
[18.301s][info][gc            ] GC(13) Concurrent Cycle 29.641ms
[11176.588s][info][gc,start      ] GC(14) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause)
[11176.588s][info][gc,task       ] GC(14) Using 6 workers of 6 for evacuation
[11176.645s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(14)   Pre Evacuate Collection Set: 0.3ms
[11176.645s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(14)   Evacuate Collection Set: 45.1ms
[11176.645s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(14)   Post Evacuate Collection Set: 10.5ms
[11176.646s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(14)   Other: 1.0ms
[11176.646s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(14) Eden regions: 1278->0(1767)
[11176.646s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(14) Survivor regions: 39->76(165)
[11176.646s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(14) Old regions: 0->0
[11176.646s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(14) Humongous regions: 23->17
[11176.646s][info][gc,metaspace  ] GC(14) Metaspace: 127295K->127295K(1163264K)
[11176.646s][info][gc            ] GC(14) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 1339M->93M(3072M) 58.169ms
[11176.646s][info][gc,cpu        ] GC(14) User=0.26s Sys=0.01s Real=0.06s
[49900.836s][info][gc,start      ] GC(15) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause)
[49900.836s][info][gc,task       ] GC(15) Using 6 workers of 6 for evacuation
[49900.900s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(15)   Pre Evacuate Collection Set: 0.2ms
[49900.900s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(15)   Evacuate Collection Set: 37.7ms
[49900.900s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(15)   Post Evacuate Collection Set: 25.1ms
[49900.901s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(15)   Other: 1.1ms
[49900.901s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(15) Eden regions: 1767->0(1076)
[49900.901s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(15) Survivor regions: 76->141(231)
[49900.901s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(15) Old regions: 0->0
[49900.901s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(15) Humongous regions: 104->34
[49900.901s][info][gc,metaspace  ] GC(15) Metaspace: 134079K->134079K(1169408K)
[49900.901s][info][gc            ] GC(15) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 1947M->174M(3072M) 65.156ms
[49900.901s][info][gc,cpu        ] GC(15) User=0.31s Sys=0.04s Real=0.06s
[65074.992s][info][gc,start      ] GC(16) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause)
[65074.992s][info][gc,task       ] GC(16) Using 6 workers of 6 for evacuation
[65075.066s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(16)   Pre Evacuate Collection Set: 0.3ms
[65075.066s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(16)   Evacuate Collection Set: 63.7ms
[65075.066s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(16)   Post Evacuate Collection Set: 9.0ms
[65075.067s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(16)   Other: 0.8ms
[65075.067s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(16) Eden regions: 1076->0(903)
[65075.067s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(16) Survivor regions: 141->87(153)
[65075.067s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(16) Old regions: 0->44
[65075.067s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(16) Humongous regions: 294->68
[65075.067s][info][gc,metaspace  ] GC(16) Metaspace: 138622K->138622K(1173504K)
[65075.067s][info][gc            ] GC(16) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 1510M->198M(3072M) 74.434ms
[65075.067s][info][gc,cpu        ] GC(16) User=0.38s Sys=0.00s Real=0.08s
[65075.750s][info][gc,start      ] GC(17) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause)
[65075.750s][info][gc,task       ] GC(17) Using 6 workers of 6 for evacuation
[65075.782s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(17)   Pre Evacuate Collection Set: 0.2ms
[65075.782s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(17)   Evacuate Collection Set: 30.7ms
[65075.783s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(17)   Post Evacuate Collection Set: 1.3ms
[65075.783s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(17)   Other: 0.6ms
[65075.783s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(17) Eden regions: 80->0(1823)
[65075.783s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(17) Survivor regions: 87->20(21)
[65075.783s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(17) Old regions: 44->100
[65075.783s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(17) Humongous regions: 90->79
[65075.783s][info][gc,metaspace  ] GC(17) Metaspace: 138725K->138725K(1173504K)
[65075.783s][info][gc            ] GC(17) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 300M->198M(3072M) 33.338ms
[65075.783s][info][gc,cpu        ] GC(17) User=0.19s Sys=0.00s Real=0.03s
[65891.537s][info][gc,start      ] GC(18) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause)
[65891.537s][info][gc,task       ] GC(18) Using 6 workers of 6 for evacuation
[65891.569s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(18)   Pre Evacuate Collection Set: 0.3ms
[65891.570s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(18)   Evacuate Collection Set: 28.8ms
[65891.570s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(18)   Post Evacuate Collection Set: 2.3ms
[65891.570s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(18)   Other: 0.8ms
[65891.571s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(18) Eden regions: 133->0(133)
[65891.571s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(18) Survivor regions: 20->20(20)
[65891.571s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(18) Old regions: 100->120
[65891.571s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(18) Humongous regions: 169->70
[65891.571s][info][gc,metaspace  ] GC(18) Metaspace: 138856K->138856K(1173504K)
[65891.571s][info][gc            ] GC(18) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 421M->210M(3072M) 33.338ms
[65891.571s][info][gc,cpu        ] GC(18) User=0.16s Sys=0.00s Real=0.03s
[65907.915s][info][gc,start      ] GC(19) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause)
[65907.915s][info][gc,task       ] GC(19) Using 6 workers of 6 for evacuation
[65907.941s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(19)   Pre Evacuate Collection Set: 2.4ms
[65907.941s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(19)   Evacuate Collection Set: 22.0ms
[65907.942s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(19)   Post Evacuate Collection Set: 1.9ms
[65907.942s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(19)   Other: 0.6ms
[65907.942s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(19) Eden regions: 133->0(134)
[65907.942s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(19) Survivor regions: 20->19(20)
[65907.942s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(19) Old regions: 120->140
[65907.942s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(19) Humongous regions: 205->70
[65907.942s][info][gc,metaspace  ] GC(19) Metaspace: 139061K->139061K(1173504K)
[65907.942s][info][gc            ] GC(19) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 478M->228M(3072M) 27.818ms
[65907.942s][info][gc,cpu        ] GC(19) User=0.14s Sys=0.00s Real=0.02s
[65908.189s][info][gc,start      ] GC(20) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause)
[65908.189s][info][gc,task       ] GC(20) Using 6 workers of 6 for evacuation
[65908.207s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(20)   Pre Evacuate Collection Set: 0.2ms
[65908.207s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(20)   Evacuate Collection Set: 15.3ms
[65908.207s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(20)   Post Evacuate Collection Set: 1.1ms
[65908.208s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(20)   Other: 0.7ms
[65908.208s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(20) Eden regions: 134->0(177)
[65908.208s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(20) Survivor regions: 19->15(20)
[65908.208s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(20) Old regions: 140->159
[65908.208s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(20) Humongous regions: 70->70
[65908.208s][info][gc,metaspace  ] GC(20) Metaspace: 139064K->139064K(1173504K)
[65908.208s][info][gc            ] GC(20) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 362M->243M(3072M) 18.382ms
[65908.208s][info][gc,cpu        ] GC(20) User=0.09s Sys=0.00s Real=0.02s
[65908.521s][info][gc,start      ] GC(21) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause)
[65908.521s][info][gc,task       ] GC(21) Using 6 workers of 6 for evacuation
[65908.543s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(21)   Pre Evacuate Collection Set: 0.1ms
[65908.543s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(21)   Evacuate Collection Set: 20.7ms
[65908.543s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(21)   Post Evacuate Collection Set: 0.9ms
[65908.544s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(21)   Other: 0.4ms
[65908.544s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(21) Eden regions: 177->0(651)
[65908.544s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(21) Survivor regions: 15->18(24)
[65908.544s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(21) Old regions: 159->173
[65908.544s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(21) Humongous regions: 71->71
[65908.544s][info][gc,metaspace  ] GC(21) Metaspace: 139064K->139064K(1173504K)
[65908.544s][info][gc            ] GC(21) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 421M->260M(3072M) 22.693ms
[65908.544s][info][gc,cpu        ] GC(21) User=0.12s Sys=0.00s Real=0.03s
[65909.154s][info][gc,start      ] GC(22) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause)
[65909.154s][info][gc,task       ] GC(22) Using 6 workers of 6 for evacuation
[65909.176s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(22)   Pre Evacuate Collection Set: 0.2ms
[65909.176s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(22)   Evacuate Collection Set: 19.3ms
[65909.176s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(22)   Post Evacuate Collection Set: 1.6ms
[65909.176s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(22)   Other: 0.8ms
[65909.176s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(22) Eden regions: 205->0(1500)
[65909.177s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(22) Survivor regions: 18->14(28)
[65909.177s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(22) Old regions: 173->190
[65909.177s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(22) Humongous regions: 95->83
[65909.177s][info][gc,metaspace  ] GC(22) Metaspace: 139090K->139090K(1173504K)
[65909.177s][info][gc            ] GC(22) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 489M->287M(3072M) 22.912ms
[65909.177s][info][gc,cpu        ] GC(22) User=0.10s Sys=0.00s Real=0.02s
[65912.334s][info][gc,start      ] GC(23) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause)
[65912.334s][info][gc,task       ] GC(23) Using 6 workers of 6 for evacuation
[65912.355s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(23)   Pre Evacuate Collection Set: 0.2ms
[65912.355s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(23)   Evacuate Collection Set: 18.6ms
[65912.355s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(23)   Post Evacuate Collection Set: 1.4ms
[65912.356s][info][gc,phases     ] GC(23)   Other: 0.6ms
[65912.356s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(23) Eden regions: 139->0(943)
[65912.356s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(23) Survivor regions: 14->11(20)
[65912.356s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(23) Old regions: 190->204
[65912.356s][info][gc,heap       ] GC(23) Humongous regions: 139->77
[65912.356s][info][gc,metaspace  ] GC(23) Metaspace: 139133K->139133K(1173504K)
[65912.356s][info][gc            ] GC(23) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 482M->291M(3072M) 21.372ms
[65912.356s][info][gc,cpu        ] GC(23) User=0.11s Sys=0.00s Real=0.02s
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say the collection pattern appears 'unpredictable', what you're probably describing is the multiple collection approaches that the G1 GC uses to collect free space across the different regions of the heap space (eden, young, old etc) which use different conditions for when that collection occurs. The 'delay' you're seeing before collection occurs is your application's normal heap usage until a point when one or more of the conditions are reached that trigger a collection.

From the docs:

> G1 is a generational, incremental, parallel, mostly concurrent, stop-the-world, and evacuating garbage collector which monitors pause-time goals in each of the stop-the-world pauses

From the docs here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/gctuning/garbage-first-garbage-collector.htm#JSGCT-GUID-0394E76A-1A8F-425E-A0D0-B48A3DC82B42

While all the collectors are configurable, you need to know what you're doing otherwise tuning at random can make things worse.

If you're looking for predictable collection times there are other collectors  you can look at instead that have different characteristics. However, if you're not running into an OOM and pause times are acceptable, I think you should evaluate whether you have a problem or not.

If you're looking for recommendations on tuning, it would help to specify what are the GC targets that you're looking to achieve? Once you have those defined, you can focus on which GC options you need to tune.